# making a playable jslider in java

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder, jslider

I'm making a grapher by using eclipse and windowbuilder that gets an mathematical expression from the user(for example  ADD(MUL(X,Y),Z)  )  and at one point asks the user to designate one of its variables as time .
then the user will be asked to choose the starting point and the range of that variable. then the program will show a frame (and a panel) that has a jslider and a play button .when the user clicks the button the program should start drawing the expression .
It should look like a [Gapminder chart](http://www.gapminder.org/world/#$majorMode=chart$is;shi=t;ly=2003;lb=f;il=t;fs=11;al=30;stl=t;st=t;nsl=t;se=t$wst;tts=C$ts;sp=10;ti=1800$zpv;v=0$inc_x;mmid=XCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA;by=ind$inc_y;mmid=YCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0TAlJeCEzcGQ;by=ind$inc_s;uniValue=8.21;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ;by=ind$inc_c;uniValue=255;gid=CATID0;iid=thlR4hyNMEnaVyV_uxRzjfQ;by=grp$map_x;scale=lin;dataMin=12;dataMax=83$map_y;scale=lin;dataMin=0.855;dataMax=8.7$map_s;sma=49;smi=2.65$cd;bd=0$inds=) .

I have checked other questions about updating jsliders but they are usually about a music player slider or a slider that just changes with time(without the graphing part).

my question is specifically about the updating of slider( the intervals can be 1 )
but it would be great if you could also guide how can I make that playable slider that it could also be used for the graphing part.

[image]
this the code so far:

```
package progGUI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class CanvasFrame extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {

                CanvasFrame frame = new CanvasFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public CanvasFrame() {
    setTitle("Graph");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 542);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);


    JLabel lblEnteredExpression = new JLabel("Entered Expression");

    JLabel lblVaraibles = new JLabel("Variables");

    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();

    JFormattedTextField formattedTextField_1 = new JFormattedTextField();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Play");
    GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
    gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 453, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 51, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(lblEnteredExpression, Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(lblVaraibles)
                            .addComponent(formattedTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(formattedTextField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 123, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(57))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 87, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(slider, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 454, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
    );
    gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
        gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(lblEnteredExpression)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(formattedTextField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 22, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(lblVaraibles)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(formattedTextField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(panel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(31)
                        .addComponent(btnNewButton))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18)
                        .addComponent(slider, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(402))
    );
    contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
  }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean playable?

Comment: I mean it updates so when you hit play button it starts for example from zero and adds to value of slider knob ( 1 per second ) 
look at the gapminder link thats what I'm trying to write

Comment: Allow the `JSlider` to control what is drawn in the graph, use a Swing `Timer` to periodically update the `JSlider`

Comment: thank you for that solution 
but how can I keep that value for drawing ?
each time that the slider changes its value a dot should be drawn and those dots should be connected to make a graph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User a `javax.swing.Timer` to schedule a periodical call back, which updates the `JSlider`'s value.  Use a `ChangeListener` attached to the `JSlider` to drive the graph, for example...

[image: Slider]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer timer;
        private JSlider slider;
        private JButton button;
        private JTextField field;

        public TestPane() {
            slider = new JSlider();
            field = new JTextField(4);
            button = new JButton(">");
            add(slider);
            add(button);
            add(field);

            slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    field.setText(Integer.toString(slider.getValue()));
                }
            });
            slider.setValue(0);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        stopTheClock();
                    } else {
                        startTheClock();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int value = slider.getValue() + 1;
                    if (value >= slider.getMaximum()) {
                        stopTheClock();
                    } else {
                        slider.setValue(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        protected void startTheClock() {
            slider.setValue(0);
            timer.start();
            button.setText("[]");
        }

        protected void stopTheClock() {
            timer.stop();
            button.setText(">");
        }

    }

}
```

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [How to Use Sliders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html) for more details

Comment: thank you for your great answer!
but I cannot implement your code to mine 
I've tried so many times in the last day but the code doesn't identify objects like slider and timer in the whole class 
can you help me to add your code to the one I've put in the question?