# drawing a graph using an updating JSlider

Tags: java, swing, graph, event-handling, jslider

I'm making a grapher that draws a graph from a mathematical expression given by user .additionally the program has a slider and play button that user can choose a variable for the slider and its range so upon clicking the play button the slider will start from minimum range to maximum and the graph will be drawn.
for the timer I'm using the answer from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28472769/4153713).

for the grapher I'm using [This](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=5276&lngWId=2) code. (I'm working specifically on Plotter.java file)

The edited Plotter.java file with the playable slider(timer) code :

```
import java.util.*;


public class Plotter extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{   

private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
private JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
private JMenuItem openMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Open");
private JMenuItem saveMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Save");
private JMenuItem exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
private int value;
private JComboBox eqCombo = new JComboBox();
private JButton addButton, removeButton, clearButton ;
private Graph graph;
private JPanel userPanel , sliderPanel;

private JSlider slider_1 = new JSlider();
private JButton playButton = new JButton();
private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
private Timer timer ;
private ImageIcon playIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/play.png"));
private ImageIcon pauseIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/pause.png"));

public Plotter(double lowX, double highX, double frequency, String file) throws GraphArgumentsException, IOException
{
    super("Plotter");
    textField.setBounds(266, 11, 134, 28);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    createNewGraph(lowX, highX, frequency, file);
    createLayout();
    //createsliderpanel();
}

private void createLayout() throws GraphArgumentsException
{
    Container c = getContentPane();
    setSize(850,600);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    c.add(graph);
    c.add(userPanel);

    JPanel down = new JPanel();
    down.setBounds(0, 437, 650, 119);
    getContentPane().add(down);
    down.setLayout(null);
    slider_1.setValue(0);
    slider_1.setMajorTickSpacing(5);
    slider_1.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider_1.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider_1.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider_1.setBounds(145, 51, 467, 42);

    down.add(slider_1);
    playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    playButton.setBounds(16, 51, 117, 29);
    playButton.setIcon(playIcon);
    down.add(playButton);

    down.add(textField);

    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(649, 39, 201, 517);
    getContentPane().add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
//  c.add(sliderPanel , BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    createMenuBar();
}



/**
 * Creates a new Graph instance and adds equations from file into Graph
 * @param eqFile file where equations are stored
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void createNewGraph(double minX, double maxX, double freq, String eqFile) throws GraphArgumentsException, IOException
{
    Equation[] eq = null;
    graph = new Graph(minX, maxX, freq);
    graph.setBounds(0, 39, 650, 396);

    eq = readEquationsFromFile(eqFile);

    if (eq != null)
        addEquation(eq);

    graph.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    userPanel = createUserPanel(eq);
}

private void createMenuBar()
{
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    fileMenu.add(openMenuItem);
    fileMenu.add(saveMenuItem);
    fileMenu.addSeparator();
    fileMenu.add(exitMenuItem);
    openMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    saveMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

/**
 * Create user panel at top of the GUI for adding and editing functions
 * @param eq equation list to add into the combo box
 * @return panel containing buttons and an editable combo box
 */
private JPanel createUserPanel(Equation[] eq)
{
    JPanel up = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    up.setBounds(0, 0, 844, 39);
    eqCombo.setEditable(true);

    if (eq != null)
    {
        //Add all equations into the combo box
        for (int i = 0; i < eq.length; i++)
            eqCombo.addItem(eq[i].getPrefix());
    }

    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    clearButton = new JButton("Clear");

    addButton.addActionListener(this);
    removeButton.addActionListener(this);
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);

    up.add(eqCombo);
    up.add(addButton);
    up.add(removeButton);
    up.add(clearButton);


    return up;





}

// slider panel
/*private JPanel createsliderpanel()
{
    JPanel down = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    playbutton = new JButton("Play");
    slider = new JSlider();
    field = new JTextField();


    down.add(playbutton);
    down.add(slider);
    down.add(field);


    return down;
}*/



/**
 * Check action lister for button and menu events
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int value = slider_1.getValue() + 1;
            if (value >= slider_1.getMaximum()) {
                stopTheClock();
            } else {
                slider_1.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    });
    slider_1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            textField.setText(Integer.toString(slider_1.getValue()));
        }
    });
    slider_1.setValue(0);

    playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (timer.isRunning()) {
                stopTheClock();
            } else {
                startTheClock();
            }
        }
    });

    if (e.getSource() == addButton)
        addEquation((String)eqCombo.getSelectedItem());

    else if (e.getSource() == removeButton)
        removeEquation(eqCombo.getSelectedIndex());

    else if (e.getSource() == saveMenuItem)
        saveEquationList();

    else if (e.getSource() == openMenuItem)
        loadEquations();

    else if (e.getSource() == clearButton)
        clearEquations();


    else if (e.getSource() == exitMenuItem)
        System.exit(0);
}



/**
 * Save equations to file
 *
 */
private void saveEquationList()
{
    try
    {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("myeq.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < eqCombo.getItemCount(); i++)
            out.println(eqCombo.getItemAt(i));

        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);

    }
}


private void clearEquations()
{
    graph.removeAllEquations();
    eqCombo.removeAllItems();
}

/**
 * Load equations from file into graph
 *
 */
private void loadEquations()
{
    String file=null;
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (fc.getSelectedFile() != null)
    {
        file = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();

        try
        {
            Equation[] eq = readEquationsFromFile(file);
            if (eq != null)
            {
                clearEquations();
                addEquation(eq);

                //Restock combo box with new equations
                for (int i = 0; i < eq.length; i++)
                    eqCombo.addItem(eq[i].getPrefix());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERR4: Unable to read or access file", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Add an equation to the Graph
 * @param eq equation
 */
private void addEquation(String eq)
{
    try
    {
        if (eq != null && !eq.equals(""))
        {
            Equation equation = new Equation(eq);
            eqCombo.addItem(eq);
            graph.addEquation(equation);
        }
    }
    catch (EquationSyntaxException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERR2: Equation is not well-formed", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
/**
 * Add multiple equations to Graph
 * @param eq equation array
 */
private void addEquation(Equation[] eq)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < eq.length; i++)
    {
        graph.addEquation(eq[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Remove equation from Graph
 * @param index index to remove
 */
private void removeEquation(int index)
{
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        graph.removeEquation(index);
        eqCombo.removeItem(eqCombo.getSelectedItem());
    }
}
// Timer methods
protected void startTheClock() {
    slider_1.setValue(0);
    timer.start();
    playButton.setIcon(pauseIcon);;
}

protected void stopTheClock() {
    timer.stop();
    playButton.setIcon(playIcon);
}


/**
 * Read file and extract equations into an array. Any errors on an equation halt the loading of the entire file
 * @param file name of file containing equations
 * @return array of equations
 * @throws IOException
 */
public Equation[] readEquationsFromFile(String file) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<Equation> eqList = new ArrayList<Equation>(20);

    if (file == null)
        return null;

    String line;
    int lineCount = 1;
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Equation eq = new Equation(line);
            eqList.add(eq);
            lineCount++;
        }
        br.close();
        return ((Equation[])(eqList.toArray(new Equation[0])));
    }
    catch (EquationSyntaxException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERR2.1: Equation on line " + lineCount + " is not well-formed", "alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return null;
    }
}






/**
 * Set up Plotter object and draw the graph.
 * @param args command line arguments for Plotter
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String expr     = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your expression");
    String maxInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter max value of x");
    String minInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter min value of x");

    double frequency = 0.01;
    double maxX = Double.parseDouble(maxInput);
    double minX = Double.parseDouble(minInput);

    String eqFile = null;
        try
    {
        ///double minX = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    //  double maxX = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    //  double frequency = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        //double minX = -10; 
        //double maxX = 10; 
        //double frequency = 0.01;

        if (args.length > 3)
            eqFile = args[3];   

        Plotter plotterGUI = new Plotter(minX, maxX, frequency, eqFile);
        plotterGUI.setVisible(true);
        plotterGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERR: Invalid arguments");
    }
    catch (GraphArgumentsException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.print("ERR4: Unable to read or access file");
    }

   }
}
```

general look of program :

[image: gifgraph]

now I want to change the code so the slider will affect the grapher .it means when user chooses the range of x from -10 to 10 , by clicking the play button the grapher starts to draw the graph as slider changes the x from -10 to 10
[Gapminder chart](http://www.gapminder.org/world/#$majorMode=chart$is;shi=t;ly=2003;lb=f;il=t;fs=11;al=30;stl=t;st=t;nsl=t;se=t$wst;tts=C$ts;sp=10;ti=1800$zpv;v=0$inc_x;mmid=XCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA;by=ind$inc_y;mmid=YCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0TAlJeCEzcGQ;by=ind$inc_s;uniValue=8.21;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ;by=ind$inc_c;uniValue=255;gid=CATID0;iid=thlR4hyNMEnaVyV_uxRzjfQ;by=grp$map_x;scale=lin;dataMin=12;dataMax=83$map_y;scale=lin;dataMin=0.855;dataMax=8.7$map_s;sma=49;smi=2.65$cd;bd=0$inds=) is an example about slider and grapher should work. 
[image]

The question is how can I do this ?

Comment: `JSlider` examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20jslider); `JSpinner` examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20jspinner).

Comment: @trashgod how exactly that is going to solve my problem? I don't want to use jfreechart . 
I know how to work with jslider and the first image the code that I have right now .I'm looking for a way to make the interval and playable aspect of slider to be applied to graphing part as I've explained in the question.

Comment: The examples may help you identify similar patterns in the plotter's design.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small code which might help you get the insight of JSlider.

```
      import javax.swing.*;
      import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
      import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;


  class demo extends JFrame
{
JFrame f=new JFrame("G");
JSlider slide=new JSlider();
JTextField field=new JTextField();
JTextField d=new JTextField();
final double value=0;

 demo()
{
    setSize(500,500);

    f.setSize(600,600);
    f.setVisible(true);


    slide.setBounds(100,100,200,50);
    field.setBounds(150,150,100,30);
    d.setBounds(0,0,0,0);

    add(slide);
    add(field);
    add(d);
}


 public static void main(String args[])
          {
            demo m=new demo();
            m.setVisible(true);
            m.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            m.slidec();



              }

public double slidec()
{
    slide.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
     public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {


      double value=((JSlider)e.getSource()).getValue();
      field.setText(Double.toString(value));

     }

    });
    return value;
     }






}
```

Comment: The extra JFrame is just extra..i forgot toremove it..BTW it just works like Gapminder chart.